# Cron в облаке OpenShift

Tags: cron, openshift

Cron в облаке OpenShift ведет себя странно. Скрипт лежит как положено, в папке ./openshift/cron/hourly
Если с приложением взаимодействовать, выполнять git push или другим способом перезапускать картриджи, все работает нормально. Но стоит несколько дней не проявлять активности, как скрипты перестают выполнятся. В логах Cron пусто, просто последняя дата выполнения несколько дней назад. Переустановка картриджа cron не помогла. В официальной документации не нашел никаких упоминания об отключении приложения.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: а что говорят логи...?

Comment: в логах cron чисто, какие логи смотреть?

Comment: [Вот тут](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html) К слову на мой взгляд вам ответили верною...И добавлю от себя привязка доменного имени позволила мне уйти от проблемы отключения сервера при отсутствии активности...

Answer (score 1):

**А вот вы и приехали к особенностям их коммерческой модели!**

Всё просто: на бесплатном тарифном плане "шестерни" (gears) выключаются, когда долгое время нет ни обновлений, ни запросов извне. На любом платном тарифе (начиная с Бронзы) ограничение снимается. Так не только у них, аналогичное поведение и у "машинок" (dyno) на Heroku. На бесплатных тарифах много приложений, брошенных авторами, и это способ экономить серверные ресурсы за их счёт.

Чисто теоретически, если сделать связку, которая будет иногда (раз часа в три) дёргать приложение без вмешательства пользователя, то приложение засыпать не будет. Будет ли это нарушением условий использования и спрятаны ли там грабли против простых способов, надо изучать.

В духе PaaS иметь внешний сервис, который будет периодически выполнять означенные регулярные задачи сам, в идеале даже без поднятия вебсервера, просто подключившись к тем же персистентным хранилищам, что и приложение.